# php - why mysql text contain `[` will damage html css format

Tags: php, mysql

I insert some text contain `[` (only one parentheses, not include `]` ), then when I use mysql query to the front php page, the `[` will damage html css format.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable Order By date DESC LIMIT 10");  
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo '<div class="text">'.$row['content'].'</div>';
}
```

I notice the html output source code.

before the `[` text, the html is correct,

```
<div class="text">this is a test, no parentheses</div>
```

but after `[` text, the html looks as

```
<div class=&#8221;text&#8221;>this is a test, contain [ </div>
```

How many symbols will cause the faults like this?
and how to avoid? Thanks.

Comment: `[` should only take effect within attributes and not the content of an element, what is the html error?

Comment: `&#8221;` would indicate that something's mangling the quotes into smart-quotes or something similar.

Comment: I think it's clear that you're not showing us all of the relevant code because this should not be happening based on what you've shown us.

Comment: What encoding are you using on this page?

Comment: What editor are you using to create these PHP pages?

Comment: @Joe Philllips , I use `emeditor`, my page encoding is uft-8

Comment: Would you be able to host the PHP file somewhere for us to look at? (take out usernames/passwords)

Comment: @Joe Philllips, I have no host yet, I will find one and register.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using `htmlentities` or `htmlspecialchars` anywhere? As a sidenote, you should probably be doing something like this as well:

```
echo '<div class="text">'.htmlspecialchars($row['content'], ENT_QUOTES).'</div>';
```

Comment: Thanks, @Joe Philllips, I tired both, no effection. maybe I should do something before insert?

Comment: Hi, after I register a host, and tried in it, there is no problem. So I delete my php and apache from my own computer and re-install them, the problem is away. May be my system fault caused it. A strange problem... Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

As robertpitt said, character [ as tag inner text value should not damage html.
You have to check for something else.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that your div class is being displayed `&#8221;text&#82212;` in your second example.
`&#8221;` is the html entity code for quotation mark.  If your css is broken, I'd guess it's because the browser isn't interpreting your class declaration as `"text"` and therefor isn't applying the rules.  Maybe it isn't the `[`, but some other factor that is replacing your quotation marks with the html entity that's breaking your css.

Comment: when I move the just `[` from the myphpadmin, the html css is display correct. I am puzzled。

Comment: When you remove the `[`, does the div class name display with or without quotes?